# JTable , Celleditor , how do i startCellEditing?

Tags: java, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have JTable and couple of Cells as rows ( only 1 column ) that have Textboxes
 On Double Clicking a particular Cell , user can edit the cell
 But i have a separate Edit button part of application for editing the cells
 since there is no "startCellEditing" method on getting getCellEditor (only stopCellEditing is there )

if i call editCellAt(row,column) method (on clicking the edit button ) its removing the existing content and user has to enter the entire content again .

how do  i get this behavior ? Inshort , instead of user double clicking the cell to edit , he clicks on a edit button , how do achieve same behavior ?

Comment: please clarify what's Swing JComponetns is Textboxes (Swt, Gwt, DesktopAplication)

Comment: do you have textbox in original table as editor or as renderer?

Comment: just to be clear: dblclick starts cell editing and the current value is shown in JTextBox, and invoking editCellAt() clears current content (JTextBox contains no text)?

Comment: You have your own editor? check my solution - it doesn't clears edited value

Comment: time for a small runnable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code do not clears cell content on button click

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        tableModel.setRowCount(2);
        tableModel.setColumnCount(2);
        tableModel.setValueAt("Foo", 0, 0);
        final JTable t = new JTable(tableModel);

        JPanel comp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(comp);

        comp.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton edit = new JButton("Edit");
        edit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                t.editCellAt(0, 0);
            }
        });
        comp.add(edit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Double Click wont clear cell content , even i agree, but if call editCellAt on some other button click , it clears

Comment: i suppose you JAVA is different to mine. sun jre 1.6. Nothing is cleared.

Comment: _Always_ construct the GUI on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).